# Silverlight Template databinding issue

Tags: silverlight, gridview, telerik

I am using the Telerik framework for creating a RadGridView with child elements in Silverlight 4.

```
<telerikGrid:RadGridView x:Name="itemsGrid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="{Binding AutoGenerateColumn, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserInsertRows="True" ShowInsertRow="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True">              
            <telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerikGrid:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn />

                <telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn Header="Item 1" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Item1}" UniqueName="Item1" />
                <telerikGrid:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Group"  UniqueName="Group" 
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Groups.Items}" SelectedValueMemberPath="GroupId" DisplayMemberPath="GroupNames"  />
                <telerikGrid:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Supplier" UniqueName="Supplier" 
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Suppliers}" SelectedValueMemberPath="CompanyS" DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName"  />
                <telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn Header="Not in use" DataMemberBinding="{Binding inUse}" UniqueName="inUse" />
</telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>

            <telerikGrid:RadGridView.ChildTableDefinitions>
                <telerikGrid:GridViewTableDefinition />
            </telerikGrid:RadGridView.ChildTableDefinitions>

            <telerikGrid:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <telerikGrid:RadGridView x:Name="childGrild" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildList}" CanUserInsertRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" IsReadOnly="False" ShowInsertRow="True" ShowGroupPanel="False">
                            <telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>
                                                <telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn Header="Part S" DataMemberBinding="{Binding PartS}" UniqueName="PartS" />

                                <telerikGrid:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Tools" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=DataContext.Tools}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding PartS}" SelectedValueMemberPath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />


                            </telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>

                        </telerikGrid:RadGridView>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikGrid:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate>

        </telerikGrid:RadGridView>
```

As you can see, each row in the grid has a child GridView, the problem is however that i cant get the Combobx in the gridview to display any data, its always empty. If i move it outside the child tempate it works fine, and the Items which are in the Tools list is shown.
To access the list, which is a property of the controls datacontext, i gave the control a Name (control), and used Path=DataContex.Tools, which i read should work.

Anyone has any idea why the ComboBox is not populated with data? I have checked that all the propertie names are correct, and that there actually are data there to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadGridView and ElementName don't mix very well. In your case, the 'control' element can't be found. You could use a [DataContextProxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx) as shown in the link. It solved an issue I had that was similar.

Comment: Until Silverlight 5 is released, Dan's DataContextProxy is a godsend for handling these template/binding issues. :)